# How to set up Anylogic Optimization experiment?

Tags: optimization, simulation, anylogic

Anyone tried using the optimization experiment with Anylogic ?
I am trying to optimize a set of parameters through simulations.
Anylogic says that the objective function is called at the end of each simulation run.
The problem is that it seems to call it whenever ... I am confused.
How can I make sure it is called at the end? Is there a feature I need to adjust in the optimizer ?

Thanks!
L.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more precise? For example, what makes you think that it is not called at the end of every simulation? What did you do to make that conclusion?

Comment: Hey. I did a test, where at every steps of one simulation, I am just adding the value 1 to the cumulative error I want to optimize. It should have returned the same value for each run hence (i.e. the number of steps in one simulation run). However it returned 0. 
I think I found the issue however. Seems like the error variable cannot be declared as static, otherwise it is shared with other simulations (seems weird, I know ...). Anylogic asks the error function to be static. That's why I had its parameters as static.

Answer (score 0):

The objective function is indeed called at the end of each simulation run, it is not called whenever. This is generally due to a conceptual error in your model and some options can be:

1. You have configurations in your simulation experiment that are not transferred directly to your optimization experiment. This makes you think that the simulation is exactly the same, while it's not. For instance you are running the simulation in different dates that you expect... check all the configuration carefully
2. the optimization is running without random seed. This may cause confusion in some cases. If you are using fixed seed, be sure that's what you want.
3. One or many variables of your objective function are reset at the end of the simulation giving you always the same objective function value. In this case you have to carefully review your model.
4. Using static variables: don't use static variables if you are not sure what they do... A static variable is shared with all the instances of the class, so it's not weird when you see that the variable is shared with other simulations.

Most of the time, the optimization experiment doesn't work magically (sometimes it does) and you have to carefully construct it in order to work as desired.

summary: The objective function is ALWAYS called at the end and if you feel it is not, the error is on your side.